# Core Plot - How can you make x axis scrollable only if range doesn't fit on axis?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Does Core Plot - CPTXYAxis have a property which define minimum width of the label on XAxis? I want to avoid overlapping and make it scrollable when range doesn't fit on defined width.

i.e. What I am looking for is property like contentSize(UIScrollView)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can control how many labels get made and where they are with the labeling policy and related properties. However, Core Plot doesn't yet have an automatic way to control the axis label overlap. You can create a heuristic to decide how to label the axis and when to allow it to scroll based on the plot range and label format. If you need to, you can then walk the `axisLabels` set, look at the content layer of each label, and determine if any of them overlap and adjust accordingly.